# Why return IEnumerable for named iterators?

Tags: c#

New to C#: could someone explain, why named iterators (term I found in MS C# Programming Guide) should to return `IEnumerable`?

```
// Implementing the enumerable pattern
public System.Collections.IEnumerable SampleIterator(int start, int end)
{
    for (int i = start; i <= end; i++)
    {
        yield return i;
    }
}
```

It makes sense when class implements `GetEnumerator()` of the `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerable<T>` interfaces, but I am not sure why and how it works for methods and properties.

**Edit**: it was pointed out that my question is not well posed.(Maybe, I am still thinking in terms of C++)

Clarification: in order to use `foreach` loop on object of some class, class needs to implement `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerator` interfaces or `yield return`(i.e. compiler takes care of everything).
Example:

```
class ListClass : System.Collections.IEnumerable
{
    public System.Collections.IEnumerator GetEnumerator() {...//uses yield return }  
    ....
}
    ....
    ListClass listClass1 = new ListClass(); // class implements IEnumerable interface method 

    foreach (int i in listClass1) {...}
```

In the example above, `GetEnumerator()` was implemented, which as far as I understood, must be implemented, if you want your object to run in `foreach` loop.

However, when named iterator is implemented (code above), `GetEnumerator()` is not required and only `IEnumerable<T>`(or non generic) must be returned by method/property.

Hopefully, this clarifies my question.

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean. The method is returning a reference to an iterable/enumerable object... can you explain your confusion more clearly? (I realize this can be difficult.)

Comment: What's your alternative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, I'd say that it should return `IEnumerable<T>` - or `IEnumerable<int>` in this case. But the reason is *because that works*, and because iterator blocks (methods with the `yield` syntax) can implement that pattern for you. If you wanted to do something *else* that worked with `foreach`, you would have to write your own `CustomEnumerable` / `CustomIterator`, and manually implement the state-machine in the iterator, using the `MoveNext()` / `Current` pattern, remembering to put any `finally` etc in the `Dispose()`. Lots of work; not much gain.

---

Edit: here's a poorly written, probably buggy implementation of doing it the hard way, i.e. returning a custom iterator by hand. Note that returning an `int[]` or `List<int>` would be really simple, but significantly changes the semantic: it is no longer a spooling iterator, which is what `yield` creates:

```
static CustomEnumerable SampleIteratorHard(int start, int end)
{
    return new CustomEnumerable(start, end);
}
class CustomEnumerable
{
    private readonly int start, end;
    public CustomEnumerable(int start, int end)
    {
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }
    public CustomIterator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new CustomIterator(start, end);
    }
}
class CustomIterator
{
    private readonly int start, end;
    int i, state, value;
    public CustomIterator(int start, int end)
    {
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
        start = 0;
    }
    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        if (state == 2) return false;
        if (state == 0)
        {
            i = start - 1; // to leave space for the ++
            state = 1;
        }
        if (state == 1)
        {
            i++;
            if (i <= end)
            {
                value = i;
                return true;
            }
        }
        state = 2;
        return false;
    }
    public int Current {  get {  return value; } }
}
```